# Jade get object children with loop in loop

Tags: node.js, express, pug

I want to loop object data that is passed via Router. I can loop first level of object just fine, but when I add try to loop children jade prompts me `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined. The code:

this part works just fine:

```
- each item in index
    - var module = item
    h3= item.name
    p Included: #{item.path}
    p= item.children
```

I even see children as `[object Object],[object Object]`, but when I add another loop:

```
- each item in index
    - var module = item
    h3= item.name
    p Included: #{item.path}
    p= item.children

    - var children = item.children
    - each child in children
        +module(child)
```

It does not work anymore. What could be the reason for this?

Comment: Not sure, just guessing. `children` is a plain object so you need to use `each child, key in children`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found my mistake: element cannot be empty, so it is good practice to check your variables before looping. Some of the children were empty, thus prompting `Cannot read property 'length' of undefined`.

```
- each item in index
    - var module = item
    h3= item.name
    p Included: #{item.path}

    if item.children
        - var children = item.children
        - each child in children
            +module(child)
    hr
```

This works.